# A complicated SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables.

> TableA -> Posts (id, title, user_id,..., created_at,..)

and

> tableB -> Reposts (id, post_id, user_id,...created_at,...)

So, in my rails app controller:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ? OR id IN ( select post_id from reposts where user_id=? )", '1', '1'], :limit => 9)
```

It works fine, but:

I need to ORDER BY my @posts by **a combine** of two columns "created_at" (created_at of table POSTS and created_at of table REPOSTS)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Post
  has_many :reposts
end


class Repost
  belongs_to :post
end    

Post.all(
  :include => :reposts, 
  :conditions => ["posts.user_id = ? OR reposts.user_id = ?", 1, 1],
  :order => "posts.created_at DESC, reposts.created_at DESC
)
```